# Git Merge Conflicts Although the File Does Not Exist

Tags: git, merge

Could you please help me to understand this behavior:

On branch develop I have a file with two commits:

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (develop)
$ git log --oneline -- coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java                      
8509cdf Added route generator based on freemarker template
1e890b7 Added XML configuration for test objects in StaticDataInitializer
```

Then I can switch to my feature branch:

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (develop)
$ git checkout feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator
Switched to branch 'feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator'.
```

And check that I have not commits for that file:

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator)
$ git log --oneline -- coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
```

That file does not exist in working directory either:

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator)
$ cat  coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
cat: coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java: No such file or directory
```

But when I try to merge develop into my feature branch:

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator)
$ git merge develop
[...]
Auto-merging         coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
[...]
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

And I get merge conflicts (both modified).

```
BOCZA2@PC45819 MINGW64 /c/nttcloud/gitlab/coba/ZAA (feature/ZAA_tools_xmlgenerator|MERGING)
$ git status -s coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
UU coba.zaa.model/coba.zaa.model.config/src/main/java/com/zaa/model/config/Channel.java
```

What is the problem? The file doesn't exist in the feature branch! 
What is the reason for the merge conflict? 
Is my repository corrupt? 
How can I find out the reason?

Comment: What does the conflict on the file say? `git diff` right after your `git merge develop`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case I had this same issue because of the fact that file-renames in git are a run-time heuristic. (This is what Michael Monteith's answer proposes, but without a solution.)

git, at merge time, decided that the non-existing file in my branch was actually a rename of a file with similar contents that *does* exist on my branch.  Any files with 50% similarity in a single commit are considered a rename during the merge, by default. Asking git to merge with a higher threshold does the trick:

`git merge {branch} -X rename-threshold=100%`

As to why I hit this issue: it's because our team decided on a single-squash-commit strategy for pull-requests. That means that individual commits on master are *huge*, thus multiplying the chance for "renames" (i.e., similar files at different paths) within those single, massive commits.

Comment: This didn't solved my problem. For the files that I have deleted I just added as staged the deleted file and committed the merge.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue by running `git reset`.

Comment: Please mention in comment why you voted down so that I can improve my answers. I tried the solution, it worked in my environment and wanted to share. Vote down without mentioning the reason is 'discouraging'.

Comment: This didn't solved my problem. For the files that I have deleted I just added as staged the deleted file and committed the merge.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue after renaming a file and trying a rebase. I got the message:

*"com.mycompany.fileThatDoesNotExist.java needs merge. You must edit all merge conflicts and then mark them as resolved using git add".*

I solved it by removing the file with the command:

```
git rm com.mycompany.fileThatDoesNotExist.java
```

Comment: Worked for me as well, although git throws an error that the path does not match any existing file

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the modified file in your feature branch has been renamed in the develop branch?

I had a problem where master had renamed a file for example A.java to B.java, and the feature branch had made changes to A.java.
I had merge conflicts with B.java even though the feature branch had no history of a file called B.java

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check.

```
// List git-ignored files  
$ git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others

// List untracked files  
$ git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others
```

and you can try.

```
1) "" git add . "" needs u to be in the correct directory, so you can try "" git add -A "" to add everything.  
AND  
2) git clean -f
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (IntelliJ IDEA) he had problems with one file mentioned in the Event Log. Since this file does not exist neither on both branches, I created an empty file with the conflicting name, committed and could merge again.

I did see the file also with `git diff`

Answer (score 0):

I find that this happens whenever we change something about our css and js compiler/compressor code/engine/whatever. Generally just creating the files that it says have a conflict, yet don't exist mitigates the problem. It lets you commit the other files... but the problematic files still aren't committed. Then you can commit those files in a separate commit and then delete them and commit again and it's all fixed. Dumb crazy fix but it works every time.

If you are having difficulty identifying the conflict files I highly suggest the following.

First create a nice clean alias using this command

`git config --global alias.conflicts "diff --name-only --diff-filter=U"`

Then you can run

`git conflicts`

to easily get a list of the files that have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when rebasing a feature branch on top of develop. Was seeing errors about the file not existing and couldn't `git rm` or `git add` it.

I resolved the issue by creating the missing file, continuing the rebase, and then deleting the file again.